# Do left or right door choice matter in Metrico+?

Tags: metrico+

After completion of each level in [Metrico+](http://store.steampowered.com/app/373990), you are standing on a platform with doors to both, your left and right side. Choosing either of them changes your body and replaces an organ with robotic skeleton.

Does the game story varies based on my choices of left/right doors? Do the skeletons help player's powers or speed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also curious about this and it doesn't look like it does beyond changing which part will turn into a robotic part.

> In the original game you’d be confronted with a choice of two exits to a level, and be greeted by a pie chart declaring how many players went out through what door. It had no bearing on the game itself, and was more of a statement on the illusion of choice and agency. Here we have a story of the player character gradually becoming mechanical, your choice of exit door deciding what limb will turn robotic next.
>
> [source](http://kaijupop.com/2016/09/metrico-ps4pcxb1-review/)

I think that's part of the "Decide what your story is in Metrico+" from the [Steam description](http://store.steampowered.com/app/373990/Metrico/). Basically the game doesn't really have a story so you can make one up.